# Premature notice of new privilege

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

So I got a notice today that says I have gained the Trusted User privilege, only I haven't yet; I only have 19,992 out of the required 20,000 reputation, which has not changed today, or yesterday.  Is this a bug or did I somehow have my reputation go up and back down again without being recorded?

Comment: @muru, good one

Answer (score 1):

> which has not changed today, or yesterday

The database disagrees:

```
2015-01-12 20:14:52.050 -10 Post Unupvoted
2015-01-12 20:14:44.513 10  Post Upvoted
```

That would have put you very briefly over the 20,000 limit, triggering the notification.

Comment: (and if you really want to know, it was [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419973/battery-discharges-in-a-strange-way-on-lenovo-ideapad-z500/420165#420165))

Comment: How are you seeing this?  When I look under reputation on my personal info page, those two entries are *not* listed.

Comment: @psusi I'm seeing it at the raw database layer (verified separately via our internal reputation audit and via the vote audit); some things that are "done and undone" are treated as "never happened" for some display purposes. This is one of them. So while it might not appear on the rep screen, it kinda did trip the notification. Unfortunate, but not a common / large problem...

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have 20,002, and that's more than the required 20,000 reputation.  Even if it was 19,992, I think the system rounds up the reputation, and so it awarded you the Trusted User privilege.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It seems I got an upvote 18 minutes ago ( 16 minutes after asking this question ) that put me up over 20k and made the privilege actually light up on my user page.